# Categorical Variable subsetting in R

Tags: r, plot, rstudio

How can I subset my data based on “lake” and then plot the nutrients (P,N,C) versus date for all three lakes on the same plot. Another thing is that I have blanks (NA) in my data and I don’t want to replace it with zero. Because it will show that concentration of chemical is zero which is not true. Is there any way that R don’t plot any point for NA values? Looks like I get strange looking plots in R with NA values. But excel does not have that problem. (excel simply does not plot anything for blanks)

```
lake                     date    depth        P          N           C
East Long Lake       9/5/1994     0.7      21.9      254.8
East Long Lake       9/5/1994     1.0      30.1     1190.0       257.0
East Long Lake       9/5/1994     1.5      20.5      256.6
East Long Lake       9/5/1994     2.5      22.1      249.0
East Long Lake       9/5/1994    12.0     212.5     2011.6      1090.6
Central Long Lake   6/30/1995     0.6      22.9       91.1
Central Long Lake   6/30/1995     4.0
Peter Lake           7/6/1994     6.1      41.9      527.2        29.6
Peter Lake           7/6/1994    12.0     138.8     1994.0      1409.6
Peter Lake          7/13/1994     0.0      19.1      746.7        22.6 
Peter Lake          7/13/1994     0.7      19.2      21.3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subsetting data and plotting it together](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42195023/subsetting-data-and-plotting-it-together)

Comment: If the values are truly NA, you can subset by variable using `!is.na(value)` or `complete.cases` to remove entire rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for.

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
dt = fread("tmp.csv")
dt$date = as.Date(dt$date, "%m/%d/%Y")
dt[,"depth" := NULL]
d <- melt(dt, id.vars=c("lake","date"))

ggplot(d=subset(d, !is.na(value)), aes(date, value, col = variable)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~ lake)
```

This might be the graph you're looking for:

```
ggplot(d=subset(d, !is.na(value)), aes(date, value, col = lake)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~ variable)
```

Comment: Thanks alot. This seem to work except I do not have date on my y-axis if I wanted to see temporal trends in data across different lakes. looks like date is plotted as variable on the graph rather than label

Comment: @Wisconsin sorry, i don't know what you mean. date is currently on the x-axis and the y-axis is setup by variable which is P, N, and C and they have different colors. How exactly do you want this plotted?

Comment: @ Kristofersen  it is working fine. I wanted to do some further analysis. Can i do pivot table type analysis in R. e.g

Comment: @Wisconsin oh, glad it's working. your pivot table example didn't come through though.

Comment: @Wisconsin I'm assuming you're wanting to update the graph on the fly with different variables. To do that you would either have to make a function to pass it the variables or use Shiny. But that would probably have to be a new question since it isn't really related to what was asked here.

Comment: Thanks ,  I agree that. i looked at my data again and i need to do some pivot table type analysis first. I posted a new question with more detail "
"Pivot table analysis in R and plotting based on subset data." Because I have multiple values for same day for C,N,P. I posted the new question ""Pivot table analysis in R and plotting based on subset data."

Comment: @Wisconsin I've written how to do it in your new post. Please mark this as solved if you're happy with the answer.